# Election chat rooms - A place to meet your constituents

Tags: discussion, election

As you may be aware, tomorrow the [Workplace Summer Election #2 begins](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2), and we'll all have the opportunity to decide who will help with the leadership and janitorial efforts that help keep The Workplace SE running. ***UPDATE:*** *The elections have now begun!*

#### For the candidates, as well as the constituency:

Stack Exchange created an [Election Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16203/workplace-2014-election-number-2), which is a place to discuss the candidates, ask questions, and most importantly, allow the candidates themselves to come out and interact with the community. Think of this as being similar to your locally-elected representatives going door to door to meet with the people whose vote they wish to earn.

So far, I've only seen a couple of our candidates in this chat room, and I encourage more to jump in. Don't let nervousness get the best of you. Being visible, even if you can't answer every question, is a great way to stand out from the pack and help ensure your name comes to mind once users enter the virtual voting booth! Good luck to everyone in the upcoming elections.

#### *Update:  Chat Transcripts Below:*

Some of the candidates have made their way into the election chat room. I've provided links to transcripts where candidates have interacted with members of the community and each other.

I've learned quite a bit from my interactions with them, and I hope this helps in making your final decisions. Hope this helps!

For those candidates who have not yet joined us, there is still time for more interacting. Please join us.

Comment: It's been lonely in there so far :)

Comment: @enderland: Did you see my question? I think people need help deciding between you and maple_shaft.

Answer (score 4):

Chat transcripts with [enderland](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-31842):

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17060426#17060426
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17063561#17063561

Answer (score 3):

Chat transcripts with [Matt Giltaji](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-31898):

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17064338#17064338
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17065023#17065023

Answer (score 3):

Chat transcripts with [Wesley Long](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-31834):

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17084145#17084145
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17085962#17085962

Answer (score 3):

Chat transcripts with [Mike Van](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-31884):

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17103946#17103946